# Converting enhanced loop into Java 8 Streams, filter

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn Java 8. Is there a way to turn the method below into Java 8 Streams, filter, and forEach. If so, how?

```
String[] couponList = coupons.split(",");

for(String coupon:couponList) {
  singleCouponUsageCount = getSingleCouponUsageCount(coupon);
  if(singleCouponUsageCount >= totalUsageCount)
    return 0;
}
return 1;

//

for(String coupon:couponList) {
  singleCouponUsageCount = getSingleCouponUsageCount(coupon);
  if(singleCouponUsageCount >= totalUsageCount)
    return singleCouponUsageCount;
}
return singleCouponUsageCount;
```

Comment: BTW, you should fix your code. `Arrays.asList()` returns a `List`, and you are assigning it to an array.

Comment: Keep the iterative solution, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @MadhurBansal How are the two code blocks related?

Comment: How is the second snippet (which you added later) related to the first? You can't have both of these snippets in the same method (since that would make the second snippet dead code).

Comment: @Eran these two snippets are two different cases I am finding a solution for.

Comment: @MadhurBansal is ordering of the elements important to you?

Comment: @MadhurBansal ok. What's the value of `singleCouponUsageCount` you are returning outside the loop of the second snippet? Is it some default value?

Comment: @Eran it is a function that does a database call to get a count.

Comment: @MadhurBansal I wasn't asking about the method call. I was asking about the final `return singleCouponUsageCount;` statement.

Comment: @Eran Oh Sorry My Bad. Actually, if none of the cases matches in the loop, then I return the last value returned by the function.

Comment: @MadhurBansal And what happens if the list is empty, so there is no "last value"?

Comment: Why do you insist on keeping two contradicting code examples? Why don’t you remove the code example that doesn’t match what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `Stream` over the elements of the array, map them to their usage count, and use `anyMatch` to determine if any of the usage counts meets the criteria that should result in returning 0:

```
return Arrays.stream(coupons.split(","))
             .map(coupon -> getSingleCouponUsageCount(coupon))
             .anyMatch(count -> count >= totalUsageCount) ? 0 : 1;
```

EDIT:

For you second snippet, if you want to return the first count that matches the condition, you can write:

```
return Arrays.stream(coupons.split(","))
             .map(coupon -> getSingleCouponUsageCount(coupon))
             .filter(count -> count >= totalUsageCount)
             .findFirst()
             .orElse(someDefaultValue);
```

Comment: Maybe findFirst, if the order is important?

Comment: @matt based on the code in the question, it's only important to find if any of the elements meet the condition.

Comment: Upvoted for solution before EDIT, but if `findFirst` fails to find anything, [OP wants last value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421780/converting-enhanced-loop-into-java-8-streams-filter#comment105030712_59421780), not a default value. Leaving up-vote, since comment is after the edit, but ...

Comment: Thank you @Eran. Your solutions were very helpful and I really learned a lot about a new approach to write my code.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, you want a search operation to be short-circuiting, in other words, to return immediately when a match has been found. But unlike operations like `collect`, the short-circuiting operations of the Stream API can’t be customized easily.

For you specific operation, you can split the operation into two, which can still be formulated as a single expression:

```
String[] couponList = coupons.split(",");

return Arrays.stream(couponList, 0, couponList.length-1)
    .map(coupon -> getSingleCouponUsageCount(coupon))
    .filter(singleCouponUsageCount -> singleCouponUsageCount >= totalUsageCount)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(() -> getSingleCouponUsageCount(couponList[couponList.length-1]));
```

This does a short-circuiting search over all but the last element, returning immediately when a match has been found. Only if no match has been found there, the last element will be processed and its result returned unconditionally.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me a lot to reach the actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
return Stream.of(coupons.split(","))
      .anyMatch(coupon -> getSingleCouponUsageCount(coupon) >= totalUsageCount) ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with streams:

```
List<Integer> results = couponList
    .stream()
    .map(coupon -> getSingleCouponUsageCount(coupon))
    .filter(count -> count >= totalUsageCount ? 0 : 1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: In this approach, the loop iterates just once as it reaches the end condition. 1 should be returned if I don't find any suitable case in the loop.

Comment: for this, the code would need to call the function getSingleCouponUsageCount() for all cases even if it's not required. And then after that, it has to iterate in the final list to find a suitable response. It can work but I think it does not sound like an optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Pattern.splitAsStream()` for this, which directly returns a `Stream`:

```
// as a constant
private static final Pattern COMMA = Pattern.compile(",");

// somewhere else in a method
boolean found = COMMA.splitAsStream(coupons)
    // effectively the same as coupon -> getSingleCouponCount(count)
    .map(this::getSingleCouponCount)
    .anyMatch(count -> count >= totalUsageCount);

return found ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the code that you've shared. An important utility for you would be to create a lookup map for coupon usage.

```
Map<String, Long> couponUsageCount(String[] couponList) {
    return Arrays.stream(couponList)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), 
                      coupon ->> getSingleCouponUsageCount(coupon)));
}
```

Further, it eases to incorporate this into the other two implementations.

```
// note: boolean instead of 0 and 1
boolean countUsageExceeds(String[] couponList, Long totalUsageCount) {
    return couponUsageCount(couponList).values()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(usage -> usage >= totalUsageCount);
}


// better to use Optional since you might not find any such value
// same as above method returning false
Optional<Long> exceededValue(String[] couponList, Long totalUsageCount) {
    Map<String, Long> couponUsageCount = couponUsageCount(couponList);
    // use this with orElse if you want to return an absolute value from this method
    long lastValue = couponUsageCount.get(couponList[couponList.length - 1]);
    return couponUsageCount.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(usage -> usage >= totalUsageCount)
            .findFirst();
}
```